# Android: init.d script to monitor and kill a process

Tags: android, bash, boot, init.d

I'm running stock android (5.1.1) on my nexus 5 and trying to use a script to kill a process (kill_process.sh).

```
while true; do
    PROCESS=$(pgrep -l whatsapp)
    if [[ $PROCESS == *"whatsapp"* ]]; then
        kill $(pgrep -f whatsapp)
fi
done
```

I'm able to have scripts running at boot using the app "Universal Init.d", but this particular script does not seem to be working at boot. It does work as long as I ssh into my phone and run it manually. E.g., as soon as I launch whatsapp it's being killed right away.

Does anybody have any ideas what I could do to make it work at boot?
Also, a while loop is probably not the most efficient way to do this...so any ideas are welcome.

Edit1:
changed the if statement to
`case $PROCESS in *"whatsapp"*)
    kill $(pgrep -f whatsapp)
esac`

Edit2: is there a way to daemonize a script?

Edit3: I set up another script containing only one line `start-stop-daemon --exec /path_to_main_script/kill_process.sh -S`. I only put the new script in the /system/etc/init.d directory and the kill_process.sh script into a different subdirectory in /system/etc/. This way the new script is being run at boot which then calls the kill_process.sh script. But it's not running stable, which is caused by the "Universal Init.d" app: when the app crashes the script stops running. Any ideas?

Comment: At least, i would replace the `true` by a `sleep 1`. But whatever you do, it's not good for the battery...

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I never used the app *Universal Init.d* nor do I have a lot of Android experience. But I did some tests on my desktop:

```
me:~$ bash -x /tmp/x
+ a=abcd
+ [[ abcd == *bc* ]]
+ echo 0
0  # correct

me:~$ dash -x /tmp/x
+ a=abcd
+ [[ abcd == *bc* ]]
/tmp/x: 3: /tmp/x: [[: not found
+ echo 127
127  # [[ not supported

me:~$ busybox sh -x /tmp/x
+ a=abcd
+ [[ abcd == *bc* ]]
+ echo 1
1  # wrong!
```

The script:

```
a=abcd
[[ $a == *bc* ]]
echo $?
```

Conclusion: You should check the shell which the app uses. It's likely that the `[[` syntax in combination with `*` fails. I think it's busybox or dash there...

For saving you battery, I recommend at least replacing `while true` by

```
while sleep 1; do
```

But also this is just a hack. You should look for an event-based solution (cannot help you there)

Comment: I changed the if statement to `case $PROCESS in *"whatsapp"*)
  kill $(pgrep -f whatsapp)
 esac`, though I don't think this is the problem, since I can execute the script manually and then it does work...

Comment: Does this app really run the script in the background? Init script are normally not made for long-term running. They normally only do short actions and start daemons... A fake daemon in a script could look like this: `( while ...; do ... done; ) &`

Comment: The app just emulates the init.d support. I use this because the stock kernel apparently does not support init.d. Your fake daemon idea does not seem to be working: I can still run an app, that is supposed to be killed by the script. I'd need to run the script manually again. Essentially what I need is a process monitor (and then killer), that survives a reboot, i.e., it's being launched at boot. I just tried to accomplish this using a script, but maybe there is a better way? Is there a way to daemonize a script? Or write my own daemon?

Comment: I managed to have the script run at boot, but unfortunately it's not running very stable. I set up another script containing one line: `start-stop-daemon --exec /path_to_main_script/kill_process.sh -S`. I only put the new script in the /system/etc/init.d directory and the kill_process.sh script into a different subdirectory in /system/etc/. This way the new script is being run at boot which then calls the kill_process.sh script. As mentioned, it's not running stable, which is caused by the "Universal Init.d" app: when the app crashes the script stops running. Any ideas?

Comment: No. I think it's the android cgroup system which removes just everything of a process once it isn't needed anymore. That's normally a good thing. You will have to look for another app which is made for this purpose or develop your own one. and if it's only for getting rid of whatsapp, you probably want to use something like Root App Deleter